# How to show the existence of $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ as a basis of $L|K$ which is contained in $B$?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

[image]
In (2.9) Lemma, how to show the existence of $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ as a basis of $L|K$ which is contained in $B$?

Comment: It would be a great idea **at least** to put the pic straight up...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $\beta_1, \cdots,\beta_n$ be any basis of $L|K$, we can use this method to get $\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_n$ as basis of $L|K$ which is contained in $B$.